# error on window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i have rails  app where i modify some files and then run bundle instal and assets:precompile.

after that  i have error in file wich was not changed.
part of file where error happened:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openCurrentTab() {
var hash = window.location.hash || '#info'
$('a[href=' + hash + ']').tab('show')
}

$(function() {
openCurrentTab()

$('#outage-tabs > li > a').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
  history.pushState(null, null, this.hash)
})
})
window.onpopstate = openCurrentTab
</script>
```

error (in console)

```
application-76c7fea….js:24 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized    expression: a[href=#info]
```

thank for help

Comment: Wrap the `href` attribute value within quotes: `$('a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have errors in your jQuery search

```
$('a[href=' + hash + ']').tab('show')
```

Use end-with selector and next syntax: do not use # inside term, use '' for setting search term

```
$("a[href$='hash-without-#-symbol']")
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

restoring before update public/assets  files helps too